# Как в Glightbox js добавить триггер открытия галереи на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, lightbox

На сайте используется lightbox (всплывающее окно со слайдером) Glightbox js,оно открывается нажатием на картинку но нужно чтобы открывалось и на кнопку.
в readme говорится о триггерах, но непонятно как это использовать.
https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/

https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Окно слайдер открывается нажатием на ссылку, которая в href содержит url открываемой картинки. Можете попробовать продублировать ссылки, одну сделав картинкой, а вторую кнопкой.